# Apply background-size on SVG

Tags: css, svg, linear-gradients

I have a `div.stripes` that has a linear gradient with `background-size` (in the top) and I'd like to replicate the same effect on the SVG (in the bottom) using `background-size`, but it doesn't seem to exist in the docs.

```css
.stripes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f00 12.50%, transparent 12.50%, transparent 50%, #f00 50%, #f00 62.50%, transparent 62.50%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 8px 8px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>

<svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="stripes" gradientTransform="rotate(-45)" spreadMethod="repeat">
      <stop offset="12.5%" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="12.5%" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="62.5%" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="62.5%" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#stripes)" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Is it possible to keep the density of the stripes so that it doesn't change depending on the size of the container? Thank you.

Comment: Use ``<pattern>`` ?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman Thank you, I tried it but I couldn't figure out how to repeat this pattern infinitely. Can you help me?

Comment: Alas programming is blood, sweat and tears (and pulling your hair out)

Answer (score 0):

Gradient dimensions need to be set:

```css
.stripes {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #f00 12.50%, transparent 12.50%, transparent 50%, #f00 50%, #f00 62.50%, transparent 62.50%, transparent 100%);
  background-size: 8px 8px;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  adisplay: inline-block;
}

svg {
  adisplay: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="stripes"></div>

<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="stripes"
    
      gradientTransform="rotate(90)"
      spreadMethod="repeat"
      x1="0px" y1="0px" x2="8%" y2="8%"

      >
      <stop offset="12.5%" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="12.5%" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="62.5%" stop-color="#f00" />
      <stop offset="62.5%" stop-color="transparent" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="transparent" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <rect fill="url(#stripes)" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Comment: When I increase the width of both squares by setting `width="200"`, the angle of the bars changes in SVG, but doesn't change in CSS. How can I maintain the 45 degree angle?